# Where's Pyglet mainloop?

Tags: python, pyglet

Consider the following example:

```
import pyglet

def foo():
    print("I'm in a loop...")

def main():

    w = pyglet.window.Window()

    @w.event
    def on_draw():
        foo()

    pyglet.app.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I **really** was expecting that on_draw() would draw things within an internal mainloop, but instead...

[image]

It fools me, executing the code only once. ***Where*** is the Pyglet actual mainloop? So that I can **really** update things there instead of just drawing once (Which is useless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like [GLUT's main loop](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node14.html). I actually never used `pyglet` before but in [this tutorial](http://steveasleep.com/pyglettutorial.html), it basically uses:

```
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/120.0)
```

So, you can do something like:

```
import pyglet

def foo(value):
    print("I'm in a loop...")

def main():
    w = pyglet.window.Window()
    @w.event
    def on_draw():
        foo(None)
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(foo, 1.0)
    pyglet.app.run()

main()
```

Again, I am not an expert on the area. There might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: I would never have imagined this haha (Setting the time/interval for each individual function). It's somewhat weird (Or perhaps I'm just too used to SDL / Allegro / Pygame).

Comment: @RederickDeathwill I also thought it was weird. We should read the all documentation to make sure it is the right way of using it though. Or, maybe some other expert can comment on this track.

Comment: [Here's the exact part](http://pyglet-current.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programming_guide/time.html#id1) in the docs. Very interesting...

Answer (score 0):

The EventLoop class contains the run method (pyglet.app.run) and is basically the 'main loop'.  It manages scheduled events, letting the process sleep, and manages events from the OS.  By inspecting the source, you can find how it works.  You can find it in pyglet/app/base.py.

To clarify why your code snippet doesn't work as expected, pyglet will on_draw events only when pyglet has executed a scheduled event or has been explicitly marked invalid by the OS; the logic is, why draw the screen if no events have fired that would change the screen?  If you are trying to schedule an event that is called each iteration of the app loop, then use pyglet.clock.schedule.

https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/eventloop.html

https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clock.html#scheduling

Comment: The above links are broken as of today.

Comment: The above links should be replaced with: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/eventloop.html and https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/clock.html#scheduling.